# GIZA++ :Forbidden zero sentence length 0

Tags: giza++

I have been using GIZA++ for translation of sentence when I used on test dataset an error is displayed "ERROR: Forbidden zero sentence length 0". IS there any way to avoid this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the *en-vi* corpus. (*English*-*Vietnamese*)
Because your corpus data is too long or not clean.

You should clean up your corpus data.

It will limit sentence length to 80. This is the command with *Moses tools*.

```
~/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/clean-corpus-n.perl 
~/corpus/train en vi 
~/corpus/train.clean 1 80
```

Or you can adjust manually.

Try to cut down the length of each line less than 100 characters or 80 words.